# Qt - QPushButton margin of icon needs to stay the same

Tags: css, qt, mobile, qt4, nokia

I create a set of buttons using the function below with text, buttonName, that can change in width.  The icon that appears when I click one of the buttons then justfies itself based on the width of the text; how do I make the icon stay the same margin from the right of the button regardless of text?  Don't say custom delegate, because I haven't been able to figure out how to implement that!

```
QPushButton *LayoutCreator::createButton(const QString &buttonName) {

   QIcon ico;
   ico.addPixmap(QPixmap(":images/images/on.png"), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
   ico.addPixmap(QPixmap(":images/images/off.png"), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);

   QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(buttonName);
   button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { height: 70px; font-size: 20px; }");
   button->setIcon(ico);
   button->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
   button->setIconSize(QSize(32,32));
   button->setCheckable(true);

   return button;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
text-align: right;
```

to your button style sheet.